# float left image doesn't come in center [responsive design]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

All I need is the image to be in the left for desktop users and in the center for mobile users. Please Help!!!

```css
#name {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-style: double;
}
img {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#info {
    text-align: center;
    border: 100px;
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <h1 class="container-fluid" id="name">A.P.J. Abdul Kalam</h1>
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <img src="./images/apjkalam.jpg" alt="A.P.J Abdul Kalam"
                     class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <h4 id="info">General Info</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

[Image when viewed from mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmSG0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Display image in center. You just add css style `margin: auto;` and `display:block;` Like below.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
   img {
     flaot: none;
     margin: auto;
     display:block;
   }
}
```

```css
#name {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-style: double;
}
img {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#info {
    text-align: center;
    border: 100px;
    border-color: red;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
  img {
     float:none;
     margin: auto;
     display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
        <h1 class="container-fluid" id="name">A.P.J. Abdul Kalam</h1>
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <img src="./images/apjkalam.jpg" alt="A.P.J Abdul Kalam"
                     class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <h4 id="info">General Info</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Welcome @JatinGharat

Answer (score 0):

You need apply media-query for mobile view in this case. I given example from 767px but you can change according your expectation. You can add these lines bottom of your CSS file.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
    img {
     float:none;
    }
}
```